# Get the start and end indices of the highlighted text in lightning-input-rich-text

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

How do I get the start and end indices of the highlighted text in `lightning-input-rich-text`?

I tried

```
var startIndex = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
var endIndex = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
```

But if there are multiple lines in the rich text editor and I select the text in the second or the third line, the index values are incorrect i.e. it returns `0` if I highlight the first character of the second line.

This makes impossible to replace highlighted text in lightning-input-rich-text using `setRangeText`.

I also tried

```
let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
```

But when I'm trying to replace it with lines having line break, it is adding a line break at the beginning and the end of Hello